# Sci-fi horror film about genetic experimentation; small tentacled creature escapes and causes carnage

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I recall seeing a film in the 80s that was a sci-fi horror film vaguely to do with genetic experimentation. There was a small creature that had tentacles that escaped and went around causing carnage. This creature was somehow genetically linked with one of the main characters. This is a very vague description but other than that I can only recall two scenes – one where the creature hides in a womans bag and when she is driving, it escapes and wraps tentacles round her face and neck and causes the car to crash. The other is towards the end and a bunch of characters are standing on a floor that collapses and they all fall into some kind of liquid. Other than that there are a number of laboratory based scenes.

Sorry this is so vague, but maybe someone will be able to identify the title from the above description.

Comment: Maybe one of the Basket Case movies? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083624/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like it could be The Kindred http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091343/

[image]

It is hard to say for sure - I have not seen it for years. It doesn't seem to have a DVD release

Comment: It's a pretty exact match to the description

Comment: yes that is it. I just youtube searched some trailers and that is the one.